# When is the right instance or scenario to have multiple foreign keys in a table

Tags: sql, database

It is definitely possible to have multiple foreign keys on a table. But when is the right instance to do that?

Is it right to have an instance whereby you have 2 foreign keys where the second foreign key references a foreign key that the second table that is being referenced already has as a foreign key?

**Context**

`Id Int`
`SecondTableId Int(FK)`
`ThirdTableId Int(FK)` 
`....`

**Third Table** 
`ThirdTableId Int`
`SecondTableId Int(FK)`
`....`

Comment: That all depends on what you're actually trying to model. Without the knowledge of that, the question is pretty pointless.

Comment: You use a foreign key in a table TableA when the values of some column (or columns) in TableA must match an entry in some other table, TableB.  If you have multiple columns in TableA which must refer to other tables (maybe TableB several times, or maybe several different tables), then you need multiple foreign keys.  Think of the record for an item in an order: it will have an order number (FK to Orders table), a product number (FK to the Product table), and maybe an invoice number (FK to the Invoices table — if orders can be delivered piecemeal and different items invoiced separately).

Comment: The Orders table might have many foreign keys: for the customer, the sales rep, the delivery address, the delivery agent (UPS, FedEx, etc), maybe an invoice number, maybe an identifier for the store where the order is placed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it right to have an instance whereby you have 2 foreign keys where
> the second foreign key references a foreign key that the second table
> that is being referenced already has as a foreign key?

In that case, no.

*Just to clarify how I interpreted your question:*

```
TableA(a,b,c)
b -> TableB.b
c -> TableC.c

TableB(b,c)
c -> TableC.c

TableC(c,d)
```

So, Table `A` references both `B` and `C`, and `B` also references `C`.

This is redundant, and *should* not be used. However, there are situations where this is a valid thing to do.

For example, if an entity `A` has a reference to another entity `B` *and* have the option to reference a weak entity `C` (that is a weak entity of `B`), you could have such a double reference to make sure that the weak entity `C` belongs to the same `B` entity that `A` referenced. (If that is required by your domain).

But in general, no. There's no need to have such redundant references unless it is to maintain some sort of constraint.

*Cheers!* ^_^